# Alternative for _outp and _inp APIs in Visual Studio 2017 C++

Tags: c++, winapi, driver

I'm currently working on a migrating project from vs 10 to Visual Studio 2017 using C++. In my codebase, I've been using the **_outp()** and **_inp()** APIs to perform I/O port operations, along with **_outpw()** and **_inpw()**. However, it seems that these APIs are not available or deprecated in Visual Studio 2017.

Could someone please suggest alternative APIs or methods that I can use to perform similar I/O port operations in Visual Studio 2017 using C++? I need to handle both byte and word-sized data for input and output operations.

Comment: are they not available or are they deprecated? What library are they from?

Comment: conio.h , yes they are deprcated from VS15

Comment: if they are deprecated, you can still use them

Comment: I dont remember the time when `conio.h` was not deprecated, so if you were fine till now, why not just continue to use it?

Comment: The problem is that I have to migrate the project from VS2010 to VS2017, but it no longer exists in VS2017. Therefore, I am searching for an alternative solution.

Comment: In what context are you using them? Are you writing a kernel driver? Because even in VS10 (according to the docs) they couldn't be used directly in application software because they perform direct hardware access, which is not allowed for simple applications. (At least not in any modern Windows; it might have been different in Windows 95 or so.)

Comment: @chris_se Yes, it's connected to a hardware tester, and we use it to send data to the tester using an I/O port

Comment: But are you writing a kernel driver (`*.sys` loaded into the Windows kernel) or a userspace application?

Comment: @chris_se  userspace application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern Windows systems you can't directly access I/O ports anymore from any normal userspace application. (`*.exe`, `*.dll`) The only way to access hardware directly is in kernel mode when you write a kernel driver.

Specifically for x86 I/O port access there is one alternative: you can install the [InpOut driver](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/inpout32/), which consists of both a Windows kernel driver that was already signed (+ some logic to auto-install it on first use), as well as a DLL (both in 32bit and 64bit variants) that provides functions you can use for port access. In your case that would primarily be the `Inp32` (to read a single byte from an I/O port) and `Out32` (to write a single byte to an I/O port). To read/write multiple bytes, invoke those functions repeatedly. This way you can have direct port I/O access from userspace by means of this trivial kernel driver that just passes everything on.

Note however that if you do install that driver, you completely bypass the security model of modern Windows kernels when it comes to I/O port access, and anyone logged in on a system with that driver installed (regardless of privileges of the user) can likely perform a lot of shenanigans with the built-in hardware, possibly even bricking the system or gaining Administrator access.

The **far better** option is to indeed write a kernel driver specifically for your hardware, that only accesses the ports of that device, and communicates with your user-space application via a `DeviceIoControl` interface that can only be used to access that specific hardware device, but not generic I/O ports. In the kernel driver itself you'd translate that to the actual port I/O. Within the kernel driver you can then use functions like [READ_PORT_UCHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-read_port_uchar) and similar to do that. (This is also what the InpOut driver does internally.) Obviously this is more complicated (especially since you nowadays have to submit drivers to Microsoft), but it doesn't compromise the systems that use your hardware.

Comment: what about WinRing0?

Comment: Didn't know that existed until now. Took a quick look at it: you could probably use that instead of InpOut, but that gives you access to far more things than just InpOut, which means the security hole you're putting into the system is even bigger than that when using InpOut. Will it work? likely. (Though I haven't tried it.) Would I recommend it for anything other than prototyping? Definitely not. As I said: the best option is to write a proper kernel driver for the specific hardware.